I want to send updated color picker information back to django view each time colour picked before form is submitted
Using HTMX with Alpine.js. Trying to get dynamic update from 'color' each time a colour is clicked on the colour picker before form is submitted, I want to send the updated value back to the view function. I understand using htmx.process() is the recognised way to look for changes to content that is added to the DOM outside of the normal htmx request cycle, but I still want htmx attributes to work. However, this still does not work in the code below.
<form method="post" hx-post="{% url 'generate_yarn_colorway' %}" hx-target="#result">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div x-data="{ colors: [], color: '#ff0000', showHoverMessage: false, selectedItems: [], newItem: '' }"
         x-init="$watch('color', new_value => { htmx.process(htmx.find('#mycomponent')) })"
    >
        <label class="form-label" for="colorPicker">Colour: </label>
        <span x-text="color" id="update_colour"></span>
        <input class="form-control form-control-color col-md-2"
               type="color"
               list="presetcolors"
               id="colorPicker"
               name="colorPicker"
               x-model="color"
               @mouseover="showHoverMessage = true"
               @mouseleave="showHoverMessage = false"
               data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
               data-bs-placement="top"
        >
        <span x-show="showHoverMessage" class="text-gray-500">Choose colour.  Include main colour first.</span>
        <br>
        <datalist id="presetcolors"
                  x-data="{ colorOptions: ['#ff0000', '#FFA500', '#Ffff00', '#00ff00', '#0000ff', '#8F00FF', '#800080', '#FF00FF', '#00FFFF', '#4B0082','#40E0D0', '#Ffc0cb', '#964B00', '#FFFFFF', '#000000', '#808080'] }"
        >
            <template x-for="color in colorOptions" :key="color">
                <option x-text="color" x-bind:value="color"></option>
            </template>
        </datalist>
        <input id="mycomponent" type="text" name="color" x-model="color" hx-post="{% url 'update_color_description' %}" hx-trigger="changed">
        <!-- Button to add color -->
        <button class="btn btn-primary custom-btn btn-sm" type="button" @click="colors.push(color)">Add Colour</button>
        <br>
        {{ form|crispy }}
    
    </div>

    <div >
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary custom-btn btn-sm" type="submit">Generate</button>
    </div>
</form>

I have tried replacing htmx.process(htmx.find('#mycomponent')) with console.log(new_value) and this works as expected logging each colour to the console as picked, and this is the value i want to send back to the view function each time. The issue therefore seems to be with htmx.process().

You have a wrong event trigger on #mycomponent. It needs to be change not changed. Start by fixing that and you should be able to POST to update_color_description when the color is changed.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this problem.  I have tried both 'change' and 'changed' and neither make any difference.  Interestingly there is conflicting information out there on these two words but HTMX docs read....'changed' - the event will only change if the value of the element has changed. Please pay attention 'change' is the name of the event and changed is the name of the modifier.

I fixed the issue without using htmx.process().  Instead I used the line <input type="hidden" name="color" :value="color" hx-post="{% url 'update_color_description' %}" hx-trigger="change from:#colorPicker" hx-target="#update_colour">  in place of the mycomponent element which achieved the view update I was trying to achieve.
